# Inside tabbar viewcontrollers navigationbar changes not working from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I have created

> NavigationController(Main) - > LoginViewController -> Tabbarviewcontroller -> HomeViewController

If I add barbutton item in HomeViewController through storyboard it's not displaying in simulator.

But I can see the changes in storyboard.

[image]

[image]

Title Home1 and barbutton item not displaying in simulator

Comment: add your storyboard screenshot

Comment: @suhit -  added the screenshot

Comment: are you setting the tintColor somewhere in the app

Comment: @zombie - Yes in main navigationviewcontroller

Comment: you should either change it in the code or in the storyboard but the final would be the code

Comment: but my question is if i change in storyboard. why it is not visible in simulator?

Comment: let me explain. i presume you have problem displaying icons...can you point out which vc is that tabbarcontroller or home2 vc......i just simulated ur storyboard in my Xcode. i have no issue. I can see all....

Comment: do as i say you will fix ur problem in 10sec...do you listen....its nothing wrong with storyboard thats you making it harder....?

Comment: you missing tabbar  that has a button in the middle am i right. if you say yes  then i will upload the answer...

Comment: ok im exiting...if you dont want the answer...i have your answer in my hand....

Comment: Ofcourse i need answer meanwhile i want to know the concept of this too.

Comment: @Joe - I have added navigation bar in Home1 which is sub viewcontroller inside tabbar. So those buttons are not visible when i run though device or simulator. But i can see in storyboard

Comment: can you update your screenshot and point out where the problem is.I can't see much on the screenshot....

Comment: @Joe - I have attached the screenshot in question. After login i am not seeing the barbutton "item" and title "Home1" intead it is displaying backbutton "Login"

Comment: did you create the bar button item and VC title programmatically ?

Comment: @Joe Ok i will do. Is that the answer? i have added in storyboard

Comment: i just uploaded the answer...

Comment: keep in mind when you accept any one answer.please try to up vote as well. thats helps the others.glad i helped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this Code:** Tested in Swift 3:

**Note:** Delete all your barButtonItems and try below code.

Add this code to your Home1 VC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let RightButtomitem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(handler)) 
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = RightButtomitem
}

func handler(sender:UIButton) {
    print("Add Button pressed")
}
```

Add this code to your Home2 VC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let RightButtomitem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handler)) 
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = RightButtomitem
}

func handler(sender:UIButton) {
     print("Done Button Pressed")
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you hide Navigation Bar in NavagationController and you make custome bar After you Add in it which you want in bar .

Comment: If we hide navigation bar then i need to add in all viewcontrollers

Comment: supose you don't show back button in any VC then you simply not add in you custome bar ......
means when you set your custom bar then you make in your way .
when you make once then you only copy past it in your story board..

Comment: Now i hided the navigationbar from navigationviewcontroller. Now adding separate navigation bar in each viewcontrollers. When i added navigation bar is not extending till statusbar, instead it is coming below status bar 44 px height

Comment: First you Hide NavigationBar to unCheck show bar in main Navigation controller .. Then take one UIView that height 64 and with same screen width .... now you take one button height 44 and width 44 and set left bottom now you get one UIlabel that is tittle so set in middle and strate in back button..

Answer (score 0):

You can try it programmatically

HomeViewController ---

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { 
    super.viewWillAppear(true) 
    let barButtomitem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(handler)) 
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtomitem
}
```

SecondItemViewController--

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
}
```

and don't add barbutton in storyboard ...